# When trying to copy the css from electron app devtools it is showing empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, electron, chromium

I am trying to copy CSS from the electron app debugger, it is showing as empty. Used context menu as well it's not working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGxHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the link in the top right corner to navigate to the line in the css-file where the rule comes from. From there you can copy it.

[image: CSS-Link-to-source]

Comment: That's cool but can we have the option there only to copy